# Passing one cell of DataGridView form form2 to textbox of in form1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a DataGridView on my Form2 and textboxes on form1. When I click on one of the DataGridView rows, I want to show every cell of the DataGridView copy in texboxes of form1.

I tried to change type of textboxes to 'public' then I wrote this in form2:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
       return;

    Form1 fr1 = new Form1();
    fr1.textBox1.Text = "123";  
    Form2.ActiveForm.Close();
}
```

but nothing copied in texbox1 of form1.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

IT's a common mistake:

the line

```
Form1 fr1 = new Form1();
```

creates a new instance of Form1 and the var fr1 doesn't refers to the original Form1 displayed.
To solve this kind of problem you need to pass the original instance of Form1 to the constructor of Form2, save the reference in a global instance var and use that reference inside form2. For example:

CALLING:
    Form2 fr2 = new Form2(this)

FORM2 CONSTRUCTOR:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
     private Form1 _caller = null;

     public Form2(Form1 f1)
     { 
         _caller = f1;
     }
}
```

DATAGRIDVIEW_CELLCLICK

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(....)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)     
       return;     

    _caller.textBox1.Text = "123";       
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you written *_caller.textBox1.Text*?